# Wide Input Voltage Range Constant Current Source

Tags: current, current-source

I would like to design a Constant Current Source of 25mA, With Input varying from 2V to 50V. Please provide just an idea how to get about this.

Comment: What kind of accuracy and output impedance do you need?

Comment: Can you use a current sink or does it have to be a source? Make sure you know what each of those means.

Comment: @Kyran It has to be a source

Comment: Specify what load resistance range you need for this to work when the supply (input) is at 2V and at 50V whilst respecting ohms law!

Answer (score 1):

LM317HV, 50 ohm resistor, couple of caps, done.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwDjy2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The LM317 (or LMx17) in current source mode works as a current source since the LM317 makes the voltage at its `Adj` terminal 1.25 V less than the voltage at its `Out` terminal. So `1.25V = 50 ohms / 0.025 Amps`. You need the HV part due to your 50V input range. The capacitors tend to keep the regulator happier - values can vary.

Per the [TI datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm317hv.pdf) suggested applications for current source mode, C1 could be 0.1uf and C2 could be omitted.

Per the moved goalposts, replace the 55v source with a 55V source consisting of a (probably multi-stage) boost converter to make 55V from 2-50V. Details of implementing that left to whoever wants to see where the goalposts move next. Presumably some sort of initial sense of the applied voltage will be required to determine where to connect the input to the stages of the booster, based on looking at input ranges for a few parts that might nearly do the job, but which have issues with the full range.

Comment: I feel that this answer is not of sufficient effort, nor explanation.

Comment: Very good, thank you. It may be useful to link the datasheet of an example of this IC, [like this](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm317hv.pdf)

Comment: This circuit is not able to meet the requirements. The LM317HV has a dropout voltage of roughly 1.5 V at 20 mA, so the minimum input voltage for this circuit is 2.75 V (and then you can drive only a short).

Comment: This is true @Arsenal perhaps the OP's requires are not quite so strict that this solution may still be valid

Comment: If the last 0.75V and/or high compliance output voltages are required from a 2-3V input, a boost converter could be pre-pended (if the 2V source actually has adequate current/power available.) If high compliance voltages are needed from a 2V input, one will be needed in any case.

Comment: The output has a 2k ohm load. I felt that use of LM317/LT3092 would not work for 2V Input

Comment: @user1589759 A 2K load means you will need a supply voltage exceeding 50V to get 25mA!

Comment: @user1589759 - next time, try putting the details required in the question. That's a rather serious change of goalposts. In any case, what you will then need without question is a boost converter, and if you want it to run from 2V your 2V source will probably need to supply an amp or more (depends on conversion efficiency) to get 50V @ 25 mA out.